# How to create search box in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have implemented search box for my website by using php, html and jquery.

Firstly, I have created a database,
using php I have sorted the values and
using jquery and html I have shown the search result in a div below the search box.

My problem is that I am not able to select the result using down or up key, for this I also tried to make the result in list or drop box in php.

Please correct me if I am wrong some where. Below is the code which is I am using.

```
<body>

    <h1>Search web page</h1>
    <form action="search_demo.php" method="post"  >

        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search here" onkeydown="searchq();" />
        <input type="submit" value=">>" />

        <div id="output" style="z-index: 10; position: absolute ; background-color: yellow;">

        </div>
        <div id="stable" style="">

        </div>

    </form>
</body>
```

```js
 <script>
        function searchq(){
            var searchtxt = $("input[name='search']").val();
            $.post("search_demo12.php", {searchval : searchtxt}, function(output) {
                 $("#output").html(output);
            });

        }    
    </script>
```

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if(isset($_POST['searchval'])){
    $search = $_POST['searchval'];
   // $search = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$search);

    $pieces = explode(" ", $search);
    $pieces_count = count($pieces);

//    $pieces[0] = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i"," ",$pieces[0]);
  //  $pieces[1] = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i"," ",$pieces[1]);


    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = "select * from search_demo where fname like '%$search%' or lname like '%$search%'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

                 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                     $pname = $row['fname'];
                     $purl = $row['lname'];
                     //if($piece == $row['brand']){

                    $output .= '<option>'.$pname.' '.$purl.'</option>'; 



                 }

    }

echo ($output);
```

Comment: What is the issue? Error?

Comment: @Umair  Thanks, normally when we search, the result can be selected using down or up arrow key. I am able to select in my case, This  is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you cannot select results using up and down keys?

I think it is because you are not wrapping `options` in `select` list . Do this

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
   $pname = $row['fname'];
   $purl = $row['lname'];
   //if($piece == $row['brand']){

   $output .= '<option>'.$pname.' '.$purl.'</option>'; 



}
echo "<select>".$output."</select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think that it's better to use onkeyup() JavaScript function as you are implementing live search and need output to be changed dynamically..